# How To match servertime and client time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two `text-boxes` and each having `date-picker` control.In one text-box the time is automatically populating when the page is loaded. And in another text-box a user have to select the time.So he is selecting its taking the system time.So its mismatching.

I am using http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-terms.htm  this datepicker control

So is it possible while user select a date from date-picker it ll automatically convert to UTC time? Or else is there any other way to do? Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of datepicker? You should really show your HTML and/or JavaScrtipt.

Comment: http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-terms.htm    this date picker control i am using

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible while user select a date from date-picker it ll
>   automatically convert to UTC time?

In JQuery you can convert a date to UtcDate -

```
var d = new Date(2014,2,21,15,58,50,50);
alert(d.toUTCString());
```

Then pass the converted string to server.